# Why elFinder file manager can't save edited file, or delete a file or even create archive as it is supposed to do?

Tags: permissions, apache2, filemanager

I'm using apache on kubuntu, i wished to use a web file manager like famous cpanel on internet does, so i installed elFinder 2.0 into var/www/html/

The elFinder is shown on my firefox webbrowser, but when i'm trying to save edited file, it popups me an Error message , and when i'm trying to delete any file, it shows me Unable to remove "style.css". I got something like that when i'm trying to create an archive as well.

I thought that is was due to permissions on ubuntu, then i used sudo shown commands and chmod but i got the same problem.

Please, what should i do to make elFinder work properly? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and It was due to the JQuery version. ElFinder seems to have issue with Jquery 1.8.x.
It works for me with 1.7.1 version of JQuery.

Hope it can help.